# Atk4 and popup from examples

Tags: atk4

im trying to get to work simple pop-up, form the examples, but none is working..

Using 4.3.0.dev.

Tried from here:
http://book.agiletoolkit.org/views/popover.html

```
$i = $this->add('Icon')->set('window');
$pop = $this->add('View_Popover');
$pop->add('HelloWorld');
$i->js('click', $pop->showJS());
```

Or from here:
http://www4.agiletoolkit.org/css/popover

```
//The view to click (can be any element)
$view = $this->add('View')->set('Some text');
//Popover view
$pop = $this->owner->add('View_Popover');
$pop->add('View')->set('Content to show in tooltip');
$this->on('click','#'.$view->name,$pop->showJS($this->js(null, '$(this)'),array(
    'width'=>'250px',//You can specify the width of tooltip
    'my'=>'left bottom',//Specify the position of the tooltip
    'at'=>'left+5 bottom-25',//Specify the margins
    'class' => 'atk-popover atk-popover-bottom-left',//Specify where to show
)));
```

On both examples i get js error:

```
Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'open'  jquery-2.0.3.min.js:4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what happened yesterday, maybe i was too tired, but it's working now..